# Subtract between two sets if one has value in the same row

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-8.1, worksheet-function

In one row I have two possible places for times to be completed, *Day Shift* and *Night Shift*.

I want to do a simple subtraction where the cells are completed (Example  `=O9-S9`  or `=K9-G9` where there are numbers placed in the set.)

Is this possible and what would the formula be?

Comment: just do "=HOURS(O9-S9)"? I am confused as to what you are having a problem with.

Comment: I Am waiting to do "=HOURS(O9-S9) or = HOURS(K9 - G9) depending on which set was filled in Day or Night in this case. As I am planning on locking down the sheet at the end so no changes can be made to the formulas on it. I need to try and make a time sheet as basic as possible for an end user with little to no computer experience...

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you said in the comments you can do this one of two ways.  You can either make a conditional statement based on their input or you can make the assumption that the users won't fill out both sections of data.

If you are using a conditional statement use this:

```
=IF(O9="",IF(S9="",HOURS(K9-G9),HOURS(O9-S9)),HOURS(O9-S9)
```

You are basically saying if either S9 or O9 are blank to use K9 and G9, otherwise use S0 and O9.

The second option like I discussed is simply to add the total together which would be much simpler:

```
=HOURS(O9-S9) + HOURS(K9 - G9)
```

Let me know if you need any additional help.

Comment: Thank You, that worked. I was trying to over complicate a simple thing.

Comment: Can you mark my answer correct then please?